# Optimize building a new array column from other dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I have the following 3 dataframes that I am trying to combine:

**Leads**

```
                   Id            Name              Title
0  00Q6F00000zEkMXUA0       V.B Swamy  Managing Director
1  00Q6F00000zEkMXUA1    Vandana Suri      Founder & CEO
2  00Q6F00000zEkMXUA2      Jane Smith            Advisor
```

**Campaigns**

```
                    Id                      Name    NumberOfLeads
0   7016F000001Oo2xQAC        Testing Campaign A                1
1   7016F000001bHoHQAU        Testing Campaign B                2
```

**Campaign Members**

```
             CampaignId              LeadId
0    7016F000001Oo2xQAC  00Q6F00000zEkMXUA0
1    7016F000001bHoHQAU  00Q6F00000zEkMXUA0
2    7016F000001bHoHQAU  00Q6F00000zEkMXUA1
```

The final output I am trying to get to is:

**Leads with Campaigns**

```
                   Id            Name              Title                   Campaigns
0  00Q6F00000zEkMXUA0       V.B Swamy  Managing Director      ['Testing Campaign A', 'Testing Campaign B']
1  00Q6F00000zEkMXUA1    Vandana Suri      Founder & CEO      ['Testing Campaign B']
2  00Q6F00000zEkMXUA2      Jane Smith            Advisor      []
```

The above output is generated by getting the list of **Campaign Members** (which are Leads) for each **Campaign**, and then adding that info as a new **Campaigns** column in the Leads dataframe.

I was able to implement this myself with the following logic, but am running into issues when the **Leads** and **Campaign Members** dataframes are very large. My machine runs out of memory half way through processing the data.

```py
# List of all campaign names we process
campaign_keys = []

for index, row in campaigns.iterrows():
    cname = row['Name']
    cid = row['Id']

    # Get members of this campaign
    matching_members = campaign_members[campaign_members['CampaignId'] == cid]
    
    # Create dataframe of campaign member lead ids
    campaign_df = matching_members['LeadId'].to_frame()
    campaign_df = campaign_df.rename(columns={'LeadId': 'Id'})
    campaign_df[cname] = 1

    # Add to array
    campaign_keys.append(cname)

    # Merge the campaign members with the leads df
    leads_df = leads_df.merge(campaign_df, how='left', left_on='Id', right_on='Id')

    
# Get only the columns for the campaigns we loaded
cdf = leads_df[campaign_keys]

# Build campaigns column
lists_entry = cdf.eq(1).apply(lambda x: list(x.index[x]), axis=1)
leads_df['Campaigns'] = lists_entry

# Drop all List columns
leads_df.drop(campaign_keys, axis=1)
```

How can I optimize this code to handle larger payloads and more campaigns?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @mapf The Campaign Members dataframe is used in the logic to determine which Leads belong to which Campaigns. The final output maps Leads -> a list of Campaigns (via the Campaign Members dataframe)

Comment: @mapf I don't think there's any typo – I've just updated my sample to include a few more cases here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

1. `merge` the campaigns and members frames on the "CampaignId"
2. `groupby` and create lists of campaigns for each "LeadId"
3. `merge` the leads DataFrame with the newly created frame

```
campaign_members = campaigns.merge(members, left_on="Id", right_on="CampaignId", how="right")
campaign_lists = campaign_members.groupby("LeadId")["Name"].agg(list)
output = leads.merge(campaign_lists.rename("Campaigns"), left_on="Id", right_index=True, how="left")

>>> output

                    Id          Name                    Title               Campaigns
0   00Q6F00000zEkMXUA0     V.B Swamy        Managing Director       ['Testing Campaign A', 'Testing Campaign B']
1   00Q6F00000zEkMXUA1  Vandana Suri            Founder & CEO       ['Testing Campaign B']
2   00Q6F00000zEkMXUA2    Jane Smith                  Advisor
```

Comment: This would just combine the three dataframes together. I'm trying to get that final Campaigns array column I listed in the question

Comment: And how is the "Campaigns" column in the result not what you want? If it isn't, can you please expand your example?

Comment: I explained in the question, but basically the **Campaigns** column would part of the **Leads** Dataframe and would be an array of all the columns the Lead is part of. Does that clarify?

Comment: I mean your output does contain only one element per list so it's a bit difficult to understand. Can you include a case where the list is larger?

Comment: I've updated my original example with some more cases. One lead which is in 2 campaigns, and another which is in none. Does that help?

Comment: Testing locally now. What are your thoughts on performance of your solution vs what I had listed in my original question? Should yours be faster / use less memory?

Comment: Mine will definitely be faster. Looping over DataFrames is never encouraged. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/9857631) excellent answer.